# Copy range from Excel sheet to table in PowerPoint using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, range, powerpoint

I tried this code for copying a range from an Excel sheet to a table in PowerPoint but it was not run.

```
ppapp.Visible = True 
For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets 
If sh.Name Like "E_KRI" Then ppapp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Add   
     ppapp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutBlank 
     ppapp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide 
     ppapp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count Set ppSlide = 
     ppapp.ActivePresentation.Slides(ppapp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count) 
     ppSlide.Select 
     iLastRowReport = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     Range("A3:J" & iLastRowReport).Copy
     Set tbl = ppapp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Table
     tbl.Cell(5,3).Shape.paste
```

Comment: Could you Post the rest of your code ? where do you set the PowerPoint application object, Presentation object, Slide number, etc.

Comment: @Luu nguyen Can you edit your question so we can see your code properly with the format?

Comment: Kindly see the code above again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the following code:

1. It sets the PowerPoint app, Pres and slide selections settings.
2. Loops through all shapes in the selected slide, and looks for the shape of Table type.
3. Copies the Range from Excel Worksheet.
4. It selects whatever Table Cell you want as the first row and column to copy the Excel range.
5. Paste into exisiting table using either the PowerPoint Table format, or the Excel Range format.

   ```
   Public Sub ExcelRange_to_PPT_Table()

   Dim ppApp                               As PowerPoint.Application
   Dim ppPres                              As PowerPoint.Presentation
   Dim ppTbl                               As PowerPoint.Shape


   On Error Resume Next
   Set ppApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
   On Error GoTo 0

   If ppApp Is Nothing Then
       Set ppApp = New PowerPoint.Application
       Set ppPres = ppApp.Presentations.Item(1)
   Else
       Set ppPres = ppApp.Presentations.Item(1)
   End If

   ppApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Select
   ppPres.Windows(1).Activate


   ' find on Slide Number 1 which object ID is of Table type (you can change to whatever slide number you have your table)
   With ppApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes
       For i = 1 To .count
           If .Item(i).HasTable Then
               ShapeNum = i
           End If
       Next
   End With

   ' assign Slide Table object
   Set ppTbl = ppApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(ShapeNum)

   ' copy range from Excel sheet
   iLastRowReport = Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
   Range("A3:J" & iLastRowReport).Copy

   ' select the Table cell you want to copy to >> modify according to the cell you want to use as the first Cell
   ppTbl.Table.Cell(3, 1).Shape.Select

   ' paste into existing PowerPoint table - use this line if you want to use the PowerPoint table format
   ppApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteExcelTableDestinationTableStyle")

   ' paste into existing PowerPoint table - use this line if you want to use the Excel Range format
   ' ppApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteExcelChartSourceFormatting")

   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Excellent! So useful code. Thank you so much. But I have problem with that code. How can I keep the color of range when I pasted to the table of Powerpoint

Answer (score -1):

I have below code to copy excel range to PPT table.
[image]